# How to apply the proper threshold to remove edges on binary plates

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am facing a contour problem, so that you can read the license plate in a correct way, it is best to take out the contours, and thus perhaps apply some OCR.

For example if I want to use this photo, you can see that on the axis it has a white outline, how could I eliminate those white outlines in a generic way? for can be used on more license plates

[image]

I am thinking of applying a threshold in the 2 axis (horizontally and vertically) again to clean possible white borders, any ideas?

A little what I'm have made:

```
# Creating copies of the original images
output_cp = output.copy()
img_cp = straightened.copy()

# threshold
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(output_cp, 215, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
imshow(thresh)
```

[image]

But then when It suposed to work, doesn't work because it is a binary image,
pseudo-code, when `xxx` I don't know what contour apply:

```
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, np.uint8)
mask_cnt = cv2.drawContours(mask.copy(), [xxx], 0, (255,255,255,255), -1)
removed = cv2.subtract(mask_cnt, image)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(removed, cmap='gray')
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: On the axes ? What do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean axis, X and Y

Comment: Where are those axis ?

Comment: Do you mean the last image i attached?  the black lines represent the white outline of the image (horizontally), a mask was used so that the white of the original image is black as the background

Comment: My question is about the axes.

Comment: Now looking at it well I don't know if I did it at all, but more or less that's the idea, apply a mask to paint the white edges of the binary image

Comment: The axes, I mean horizontally and vertically

Comment: Can't address your question without sufficient information, sorry.

Comment: Sorry if I did not express myself well, the problem is to find a way to eliminate the white outline of the image, so that only the white letters are visible

Answer (score 1):

To remove the white margin around the plate, you can :

- find the external contours of the image with [`findCountours`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0)
- take its rotated bounding box with [`minAreaRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9)
- compute a transformation to correct the orientation with [`getPerspectiveTransforme`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga20f62aa3235d869c9956436c870893ae)
- then apply it with [`warpPerspective`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/df1/group__imgproc__hal__functions.html#ga843a5226c302e59fe09b08f424e08795)

This remove the margin and also correct the orientation of the plate which should make it much easier to read by any OCR.

Here is a python implementation of my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("plate.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# invert image and detect contours
inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(inverted,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# get the biggest contour
biggest_index = -1
biggest_area = -1
i = 0
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > biggest_area:
        biggest_area = area
        biggest_index = i
    i = i+1

print("biggest area: " + str(biggest_area) + " index: " + str(biggest_index))

cv2.drawContours(img, contours, biggest_index, [0,0,255])
center, size, angle = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[biggest_index])

rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.)

#cv2.warpPerspective()
print(size)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(gray, rot_mat, (int(size[0]), int(size[1])))

mask = dst * 0
x1 = max([int(center[0] - size[0] / 2)+1, 0])
y1 = max([int(center[1] - size[1] / 2)+1, 0])
x2 = int(center[0] + size[0] / 2)-1
y2 = int(center[1] + size[1] / 2)-1

point1 = (x1, y1)
point2 = (x2, y2)
print(point1)
print(point2)

cv2.rectangle(dst, point1, point2, [0,0,0])
cv2.rectangle(mask, point1, point2, [255,255,255], cv2.FILLED)

masked = cv2.bitwise_and(dst, mask)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imshow("dst", dst)
cv2.imshow("masked", masked)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
key = -1;
while key != 27:
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And the resulting image :
[image]

This is not perfect, but a good start I think, slightly different approche than thresholding.

You might also try to apply some morphological operator to close some gap or remove dirty parts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The last 2 options I think I will not be able to use them since they will be more than 1 image at different angles, however, to find the contours, what would it be like if I did not find them?  Can you make a small example with the second option (minAreaRect) to understand it better?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear enough I think, what I suggest is one solution made of 4 steps. `minAreaRect` is meant to be used on the contour you find and there is always an external contour, at least of the size of the image

Comment: btw you might need to invert your input image first since `findContour` takes non null pixels into account.

Comment: How could I find the contour in case a letter is part of the contour (for example, when there is a plate screw between the letter and part of the outline)?

Comment: do you have an image example of such a case ?

Comment: This image at top of letter S, and a little the number 3.

Comment: I see. This isn't an issue because the `minAreaRect` will not see those holes.

Comment: What happend if the input image it is like this? https://prnt.sc/stcpoi

Comment: With this code https://www.paste.org/106314 that you made with some input modification